# Matlab - Exporting cell arrays within cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, printf, cell

I have a 1x6 cell array. Each of the cells arrays contains a 5000x1 cell array comprising either strings or numbers. I would like to export that with `fprintf` in six columns separated by e.g. a backslash. I could use some help with that or, alternatively, on how to combine the data into a single 5000x6 cell array (I can manage to export this with a fairly simple loop).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
[ my6Cell{:} ]
```

It should return a single cell array of size 5000x6

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it does not seem to work. I get the following error "CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent". Any thoughts why that can be?

Comment: @aulky11 are you sure all the elements of `my6Cell` are `5000`-by-1? is it possible you have an empty cell in the middle?

Comment: Yes. It's a 1x6 cell and each of these cells contains a 5000x1 cell. I am quite new to this, so could it be that cells 1-4 and 6 contain strings and cell 5 numbers?

Comment: Now I see. In the fifth cell I have 5000x1 double instead of cell. It was too small to see in the preview. I have converted it to cell and now works. Thanks a lot for the help!